# Using String[] selectionArgs in SQLiteDatabase.query()

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

How do I use the `String[] selectionArgs` in `SQLiteDatabase.query()`? I wish I could just set it to `null`, as I have no use for it. I am just trying to load an entire unsorted table from a database into a `Cursor`. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: You can set them to null. Show your code.

Comment: Sometimes, the first step is to actually try something.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

selectionArgs replace any question marks in the selection string.

for example:

```
String[] args = { "first string", "second@string.com" };
Cursor cursor = db.query("TABLE_NAME", null, "name=? AND email=?", args, null);
```

as for your question - you can use null

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. @GalBen-Haim please do you think you could give me your opinion on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598696/recommended-way-order-to-read-data-from-a-webservice-parse-that-data-and-inse

Comment: Note that passing null to `columns` is discouraged. You should explicitly query only the columns you need. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: So how does it replaces ? with selection Args. Is it like first ? will be replaced by args[0]. If so what happens when there is mismatch in the num of ? and items in args[] ? . Please explain

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you may set all parameters to **null** except the table name.

for example:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("TABLE_NAME", null, null, null, null, null, null);
```