# SQLite Android Cursor sql statement

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I am trying to write a SQL query like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_USER 
WHERE theUser = userID;
```

but Android uses Cursor, and I'm not sure if I am doing this right. Can someone confirm? This is the header for the Cursor query function:

```
public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)
```

`selection`: A filter declaring which rows to return, formatted as an SQL WHERE clause (excluding the WHERE itself). Passing null will return all rows for the given table.

And this is my code:

```
public ArrayList<Goal> getAllGoals(User user) {

    int currentUserID = user.getUserID();
    String theUser = Integer.toString(currentUserID);

    String[] columns = new String[] {userID, goal, activityType, target_steps, completed_steps};

    Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_GOAL, columns, theUser, null, null, null, null);

    ArrayList<Goal> allGoals = new ArrayList<Goal>();


    while(c.moveToNext()){
        c.getInt(currentUserID);
        c.getInt()
    }
    c.close();


    return allGoals;
}
```

Comment: You are forgetting the 4th argument, it is your argument parameter. Should be something like `userId`.

Comment: Thank you, found my answer based on your guidance

Answer (score 2):

selectionArgs replace any question marks in the selection string.

for example:

```
String[] args = { "first string", "second@string.com" };
Cursor cursor = db.query("TABLE_NAME", null, "name=? AND email=?", args, null);
```

> reference:
>
> [Using String[] selectionArgs in SQLiteDatabase.query()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507005/how-to-use-string-selectionargs-in-sqlitedatabase-query)