# Query in SQLite not read in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, mobile

I've been wondering why my `Cursor` returns an empty value If I `Select` the `hh_id` fields, it works on normal number like `1234` but I observed when the `hh_id` consists of symbol `-` it returns the cursor to `null` even though it exists

[image]

```
String household_no ="";
household_no = edt_hh.getText().toString();

Cursor search = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT id,full_name,hh_id,client_status,address,sex,hh_set_group,current_grantee_card_number,other_card_number_1,other_card_holder_name_1,other_card_number_2,other_card_holder_name_2,other_card_number_3,other_card_holder_name_3,upload_history_id,created_at,updated_at,validated_at FROM emv_database_monitoring WHERE hh_id="+household_no);
           
            while (search.moveToNext()) {
                String emv_id = search.getString(0);
                String full_name = search.getString(1);
                String hh_id = search.getString(2);
                String client_status = search.getString(3);
                String address = search.getString(4);
                String sex = search.getString(5);
                String hh_set_group = search.getString(6);
                String current_grantee_card_number = search.getString(7);
                String other_card_number_1 = search.getString(8);
                String other_card_holder_name_1 = search.getString(9);
                String other_card_number_2 = search.getString(10);
                String other_card_holder_name_2 = search.getString(11);
                String other_card_number_3 = search.getString(12);
                String other_cardholder_name_3 = search.getString(13);
                String upload_history_id = search.getString(14);
                String created_at = search.getString(15);
                String updated_at = search.getString(16);
                String validated_at = search.getString(17);
            }
            Log.v(ContentValues.TAG,"hahaha " +hh_id);
            search.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of `WHERE hh_id="+household_no`.

When `household_no` contains dashes i.e. minus signs, it's a math expression that gets evaluated and the result of that expression does not necessarily match any rows.

You should at least use single quotes for literal values, such as `WHERE hh_id='"+household_no+"'"`, or better yet, use `selectionArgs` variable binding ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507005/using-string-selectionargs-in-sqlitedatabase-query)).